# Are there good tools for C# reverse engineering?

Tags: c#, uml, reverse-engineering, modeling

can you say me if there are good tools for reverse-engineering my C# applications. I need UML-class-diagrams of my written software and i don't want to draw these diagrams by myself. I've already tested StarUML but it didn't work because I used generics an something.

Would be great if there a some advices.

Greetings,
Martin

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784066/free-tools-to-automatically-create-uml-diagrams-from-an-existing-net-project

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you checked out .NET reflector? Has a [diagram](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx) plugin too..

List of [Add-Ins](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins)

Comment: Wow, have you seen the number of plug-ins available these days? Nice reminder!

Comment: It's even better than that... It also has a "Create Source" plugin which creates a a project and sln based on the dlls/exes you are examining. Now that is gold.

Comment: +1 very usefull piece of software

Comment: i've tested autodiagrammer. it's ok for my purposes

Comment: That's good :) cus I've not actually got it working before... or am maybe too impatient.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidentally enough a colleague of had a meeting with some MS guys regarding Visual Studio 2010 team foundation server. They told him that it has the ability to reverse engineer your assemblies and produce UML diagrams. A quick look on MSDN ([link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb725993.aspx)) seems to partially confirm this. It doesn’t say UML but it confirms architectural diagrams can be derived and your code which can be validated against at compile time. But it’s obviously not available yet and I’m sure it will carry a hefty price tag.

Answer (score 2):

[Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/downloadtrialumodel.html?gclid=CL6tpovkgp4CFc8UzAodqlD0pw)

Answer (score 2):

[Sparx enterprise architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) is very good. I use it at my work.

Answer (score 2):

The NDepend tool is certainly what you are looking for [C# code reverse engineering](http://www.NDepend.com). NDepend comes with a [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependenciesView) coupled with a dependency matrix. You can try NDepend straight on your code thanks to a **Free Trial Edition**. As a picture is worth a thousands words, see NDepend's screenshoots extracted from this blog post: [Interactive Code Dependencies Graph](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/09/09/interactive-code-dependencies-graph.aspx)

[alt text http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.Graph/InternalDependenciesGraphSmall2.jpg](http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.Graph/InternalDependenciesGraphSmall2.jpg)

[image]

[alt text http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.Graph/CycleGraphSmall2.jpg](http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.Graph/CycleGraphSmall2.jpg)

[alt text http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.CQLExport/Graph1.jpg](http://codebetter.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/patricksmacchia.CQLExport/Graph1.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

ILSpy looks alot like Reflector.
http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx 
 
I've used it many times and it's very handy.

There's also dotPeek(Creators of Resharper)
 
http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP

They Are both free :D

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate supports UML class diagrams as well as sequence, component, use case, and activity diagrams. It also supports creating sequence, dependency graphs, and layer diagrams from code. Regarding your question about generating UML diagrams from code, there's a response here in the VS Architecture & Modeling tools forum: [Is it possible to reverse engineer C# code into an UML Class Diagram?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/a1ee9393-8f9b-45f2-8277-6e49346a119a)

Other tools include Architecture Explorer, which lets you browse and explore your solution.

For more info, see the following links:

To download the RC release, visit: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=457bab91-5eb2-4b36-b0f4-d6f34683c62a)

To see the RC documentation, see [Modeling the Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57b85fsc%28VS.100%29.aspx).

To discuss these tools, visit the [Visual Studio 2010 Architectural Discovery & Modeling Tools](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/threads) forum.