# Is there a way to create UML diagram from ios project automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uml, class-diagram

I want to create a class and flow diagram from our attractive but five years old ios project written with objective-c. The graph will show which classes and functions I interact with while using the app?

I know there are some tools for .NET or other languages where you can reverse engineer the project ([visio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784129/2103088), [visual-paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com)) and create UML diagram from it for example, but they don't seem applicable for ios projects (objc or swift doesn't matter).

Plus [OmniGraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle/) seems okay for creating the classes and models hierarchy like this[image: project diagram with omnigraffle]

But what I need is the interaction between those classes with triggers like algorithm or flow of user actions. 
For example, I clicked to add to cart button then it records...

> AddCartVC (class) buttonTapped: 
>   CheckControl (class) controlFunc 
>   ResultVC

etc.

I would be glad if you know any solution for it! Or is there any way to easily do it like monitoring main run loop fetching class and function names etc?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can not create sequence diagrams (I guess that's what you mean by "interaction between...") from pure code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have omnigraffle https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle you can drag and drop the project folds to the icon of the program and then a uml like diagrams is generated

Comment: OmniGraffle is okay for creating class hierarchy but what I want to have is specifically flow diagram of the classes with actions please see updated description.